# Lebesgue integral of $1/|x|$ on an open $n$-ball

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I happened upon the following problem:

> Calculate the integral
> $$\int_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x|<2 \}} \frac{1}{|x|} d\lambda(x),$$
> where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. The measure of a unit ball can be used as a constant.

I should already have all the necessary tools to solve this problem, but I have trouble figuring out where to start. I suppose my intuition on the behaviour of $\frac{1}{x}$ on the real numbers has become an obstacle.

Any ideas on how I could get started and make sense of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use generalized polar coordinates to compute this integral, a treatment of which can be found in Folland, Real Analysis, Section 2.7.

In Folland, you get the result (Corollary 2.51), that says if $f$ is a nonnegative measurable or an integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $f(x) = g(|x|)$ for some $g: (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{C}$, then $\int f dx = n\cdot m(B^n) \int_0^\infty g(r) r^{n-1} dr$, where $m(B^n)$ is the Lebesgue measure of the unit ball.